# Module parse failed: The keyword 'interface' is reserved using turbo repo Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, turborepo, next.js13

I am using Next.js 13 with turbo repo.. can any one solve this problem. all components working fine with previous version on next.js...

Module parse failed: The keyword 'interface' is reserved (10:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

hra:dev: > interface Props {
item?:any
fieldname?: string

i have try all things like webpack modules.

Answer (score 4):

You should transpile the ui kit module in your next config.

```
module.exports = {
  transpilePackages: ['ui'],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar problem , and solved it by adding  `transpilePackages: ["@repos/ui"]` to `next.config.js` at workspace level.

All next-transpile-modules features have natively landed to Next.js 13.1
-- nextjs